# grep in Debian and OSX different results

Tags: macos, docker, debian

I have a Dockerfile and would like to grep AIRFLOW_VERSION from it:

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION="2.1.0" <---- This one
```

This command works fine on my local machine (OSX):

```sh
export AIRFLOW_VERSION=$(grep "ARG AIRFLOW_VERSION=" /Dockerfile | grep -Eo "\d\.\d\.\d")
echo $AIRFLOW_VERSION                                                                                                             
2.1.0
```

But when I run it on Debian machine (Gitlab Runner), it founds nothing. Pulled the image of the runner locally and double-checked, nothing was found. The file is there, no issue with missing on misplaced file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue is related to different version of `grep` implementation: GNU for Debian and BSD for Mac OS.

Try to replace `-E` with `-P` like: `grep -Po "\d\.\d\.\d"`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use perl regexpr (PCRE) :

```
echo AIRFLOW_VERSION="2.1.0" | grep -Po "\d\.\d\.\d"
```

On debian, the `-E` implies Extended Regexprs (ERE):

```
 echo AIRFLOW_VERSION="2.1.0" | grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```